# How can I get the mobile carrier (gsm operator) for a windows phone 8.1 ( win rt ) application?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get what exact carrier the phone has, i have tried

```
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles().First().WwanConnectionProfileDetails;
```

It works but only if the user enables his data connection but if not, and he's using WiFi I can't get it, is there a way to get the carrier even if there's no data connection?